# Build constrained alpha shape of polygons

Tags: computational-geometry, concave-hull

I have a quite specific task.
I need to compute [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) of a set of points. (You can frolic with already implemented algorith [there](https://mikolalysenko.github.io/alpha-shape/index.html))

The point is that I have predefined subsets of points (let's call them details) and I do not want their structure to be changed. For example, suppose these polygons to be details:

[image]

Then, the following hulls are ok depending on alpha-radius:

[image]

[image]

And the following is not:

[image]

In brief, I want the structure of specified subsets of points to stay unchanged during reducing the radius.

So, how do you think:

1. May I use any of already implemented algorithm or should I figure out some specific one?
2. Is there implemented example of Alpha-Shape algorithm with open source code anywhere? (Alpha-Shape, not Concave hull. It must split contour into several parts when reducing the radius)

Comment: Why do you say that the third case is not ok ? What is wrong with the "structure" ?

Comment: Well, as I mentioned above these quadrangles are just examples of details that cannot  be  crossed by the result contours.
Why? Because of the application area of the algorithm I'm trying to find. These contours will be cut from material on the next step and it would be wrong to split the details.

Should I edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: "that cannot be crossed by the result contours": what ??

Comment: Oh, I get it. You want the alpha-shape not of the points but of the initial polygons (the term *details* is not intuitive). This is not the standard algorithm.

Comment: The same way that a standard alpha-shape is a subset of the Delaunay triangulation of the points, it could be that what you are after is a subset of the constrained triangulation around the polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Finally I solved this using constrained Delaunay triangulation.

The idea (that [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1196549/yves-daoust) shared in comment to the question) was to use not just Delaunay triangulation during building Alpha shape, but *constrained* Delaunay triangulation.

**Algorithm:** In brief, I:

1. Took convex hull of the promoted polygons
2. Computed its constrained triangulation. (Constraining segments are polygon's edges)

On this step I used [Triangle .NET](https://github.com/garykac/triangle.net) library for C#. I guess, every popular language has alternatives to it.

3. Built alpha shape: threw away all triangles where any edge is longer than predefined *alpha*

**Results** of my struggles:

1. Alpha = 1000, alpha shape is just a convex hull

[image]

2. Alpha = 400

[image]

3. Alpha = 30. Only very small concavities are smoothened

[image]

**Feel free to write me for a deeper explanation, if you wish.**